# Qt MouseReleaseEvent never triggered inside eventFilter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qevent

I have the following widget's hierarchy:

```
root (QWidget)
 |-> first child (QWidget)
 |---> label A (QLabel)
 |---> label B (QLabel)
 |-> second child (QButton)
 |-> third child (QButton)
```

what I am trying to achieve is to receive mouse release events on `first child` (or both `label A` and `label B`, the behaviour would be the same anyway)

I tried using an event filter

```
MyWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    setupUi(this);
    // some other stuff
    mFirstChild->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
        // do stuff
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

My problem is that my test `doStuff()` method is never called. I correctly receive events like Enter, Leave, Repaint, MousePress, MouseDblClick, but I never get MouseRelease (nor MouseMove by the way).
Am I missing something obvious here ?

EDIT: After some more researches, I tried using `WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` attribute, it did not change anything.

Comment: No focus probably. You only have the mouse button release event within the viewport area of first child. i. e. if you move the mouse to second child and then release your mouse button it will not trigger your installed MouseButtonRelease event. Same if another child is on top.

Comment: What should I do then ? Force the focus on the mouse press event ?

Comment: Your code should work as expected. If the mouse is released in the viewport of the first children an event should occur.

Comment: For debugging further Please check      "class CustomGUIApplication: public QGuiApplication
{public:    CustomGUIApplication(int &argc, char **argv)
        :QGuiApplication(argc, argv)  { }
    virtual bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override  {
        return QGuiApplication::notify(receiver, e); //Check whether you are getting events at this point.
    }
};"

Comment: For mouse move event try to enable http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Actually I do not need mouse events, it was more for providing additional infos. 
I will give a shot at your debbuging tip, thanks.